Why do representations of $SU(2)$ correspond to angular momentum eigenstates?
I have been learning about symmetry in one of my physics classes and specifically about $SU(2)$ and its irreducible representations. We can label a basis element of the vector space corresponding to a representation of $SU(2)$ using $|j,m\rangle$ where $j$ labels the representation('s dimension) and $m$ labels which one of the basis elements we have.
My question is this: These $|j, m\rangle$ labelings correspond to angular representation eigenstates. Why do vectors in the vector spaces mapped to by representations of $SU(2)$ correspond to states and are there generalizations of this idea to other symmetry groups?

Let us take for granted that the group $SO(3)$ encodes how spatial rotations in three dimensional Euclidean space work. Actually, we must also fix the scalar in front of the commutation relation of its Lie algebra $\text{Lie}(SO(3)) = \mathfrak{so}(3)$ such that $[L_i, L_k] = i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}L_k$. Fixing the commutation relation in this way guarantees that a rotation by $2\pi$ results in the identity rotation.
Now, we postulate that a spatial transformation on Euclidean space, the background on which our physical theory takes place, should in general affect the states we use to describe systems in that background. But, elements $O \in SO(3)$ are only naturally maps on Euclidean space $O: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. How can we possibly get them to sensibly act on states that live in a Hilbert space $\lvert \psi \rangle \in \mathcal{H}$?
The answer is a linear representation. Recall that a linear representation of a group $G$ is a map
$$\pi: G \to GL(V)$$
such that
$$\pi(g_1g_2) = \pi(g_1)\pi(g_2)$$
where $V$ is a vector space called the representation space of the representation. Hereafter we say representation instead of linear representation.
In quantum mechanics, it is mathematically permissible to slightly generalize from representations and use projective representations which are maps
$$P\pi: G \to GL(V)$$
such that
$$P\pi(g_1g_2) = cP\pi(g_1)P\pi(g_2), \quad c \in \mathbb{C}$$
assuming $V$ is a complex vector space. We see that a projective representation respects the group properties up to a constant multiple. We can use projective representations instead of representations in quantum mechanics because states are actually rays.
Hence, to define a sensible way for rotations on three dimensional Euclidean space to act on states in Hilbert space, we use a projective representation
$$P\pi: SO(3) \to GL(\mathcal{H}).$$
By Bargmann's theorem and several results from Lie theory, projective representations $P\pi: SO(3) \to GL(\mathcal{H})$ are equivalent to normal representations of the universal cover$^1$ of $SO(3)$, denoted $\text{Spin}(3)$. And, $\text{Spin}(3) \cong SU(2)$. Hence, projective representations of $SO(3)$ are equivalent to normal representations of $SU(2)$
$$\pi: SU(2) \to GL(\mathcal{H}).$$
Finally, we classify all representations of $SU(2)$. By Bargmann's theorem and slew of Lie theory alluded to above, this is equivalent to finding all irreducible representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2) \cong \mathfrak{so}(3)$. We also usually actually find all irreducible representations of the complexified Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$. This is what is secretly done by method of raising and lowering operators in canonical texts on quantum mechanics under the name "theory of angular momentum". This is done in the language of Lie theory in Brian C. Hall's Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations.
So, to answer your first question, we can think of the states $\lvert \psi \rangle \in \mathcal{H}$ as already existing and we are doing this representation theory to figure out how to implement spatial rotations as transformations over the Hilbert space. With this representation theory, we also get some nice labels $(j, m)$ that tell us how these states transform.
To answer your second question, this is certainly done with other symmetry groups. Most prominently perhaps is Wigner's classification which defines a one particle state as transforming under an irreducible representation of the Poincaré group, the spacetime symmetry group of special relativistic theories. The exact same song and dance that was done with $SO(3)$ is done with $SO^+(1,3)$ and the representation theories actually end up being intimately related by an exceptional isomorphism to do with their Lie algebras.

[1] That this is a double cover is not the point. The universal cover of a connected Lie group, e.g. $SO(3)$, always exists and is unique. Moreover, by definition it has the nice property of being simply-connected.

$\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is the so-called universal cover of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, which is the group of rotations. The representations of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the projective representations of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, which are representations up to a constant multiplicative factor. Within quantum theory, constant multiplicative factors are physically meaningless, so projective representations are just as good as representations. Hence, the projective representations of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ are the realizations of rotations in the Hilbert space, and it is easier to work with the (true) representations of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. Hence, we end up working with them.
